# How can be set an ACL policy to allow a user to only run a job on Rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

Can anybody help me in how to configure a user in Rundeck to
 
     1) only run a job 
     2) deny modification/deletion of existing job 
     3) deny creation of new jobs

I suppose I need to set this configuration in the aclpolicy.yaml file but I cannot find detailed instructions on how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Yeah.. Happy to help.

I assume you already have a project and a job in there. Say project Test and job testjob. I assume you have created a role/group on WEB.xml file as testrole and you have a .aclpolicy as test.aclpolicy. The above stuffs have detailed documentation on Rundeck, however it's true they don't have better documentation on various rd-acl use cases.

In your case, if you want your user "testuser" to just run/read/kill a job execution, use the below test.aclpolicy.

```
---
for:
  job:
  - allow:
    - runAs
    - killAs
    - kill
    - read
    - run
    equals:
      name: testjob
  node:
  - allow:
    - read
    - run
  adhoc:
  - deny:
    - read
    - run
  resource:
  - allow: read
    equals:
      kind: event
description: generated
context:
  project: Test
by:
  group: testrole

---
 for:
  project:
  - allow: read
    equals:
      name: Test
description: generated
context:
  application: rundeck
by:
  group: testrole
```

In case if you wanted to give same privilege to multiple jobs in a same project for the same user, just replace "equals" with "match" and under name parameter, enter your jobs separating a pipe "|" like "testjob1|testjob2"..

Answer (score 1):

If you need a user with permission to execute all jobs in all projects you can configure the next policy (little modification from Leo answer):

```
---
description: 'Allow group runjob to run all jobs'
for:
  job:
  - allow:
    - runAs
    - killAs
    - kill
    - run
    - read
    match:
      name: '.*'
  node:
  - allow:
    - read
    - run
  adhoc:
  - deny:
    - read
    - run
  resource:
  - allow: read
    equals:
      kind: event
context:
  project: '.*'
by:
  group: runjob

---
description: 'Allow '
for:
  project:
  - allow: read
    match:
      name:  '.*'
context:
  application: rundeck
by:
  group: runjob
```

Comment: That's true. But acl is always meant for narrowing the access levels. If needed to have a role with users to work on all jobs, better copy the admin user acl policy with separate user name.